# How to take only numbers in a string?

Tags: java

If you prompt the user for a price and they input $25.50, how would I take out the numbers and store them as a Double so that I can use them in equations.

I have tried,

```
    System.out.println("What is the price of the product(e.g. 35.21)?");
    price = scanner.nextLine();
    price_2 = price.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    price_3 = Double.parseDouble(price_2);
    System.out.println(price_3);
```

But it does not maintain the decimal.

Comment: What do you mean outputted to a double value?

Comment: can you give us sample input and output?

Comment: You need to put in more of an effort when asking, adding some sample data and some code that you have written so far and overall a better explanation of what you want to achieve

Comment: Define your string. How is it formatted? Can it be parsed? Is it a random format?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Downvoting and asking for an MCVE in such a simple case is a little ridiculous, especially since a valid MCVE could be created by just dropping the posted code into a `private static void main()` method and a new `Scanner` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `regex` to strip out all non-numeric characters from the String, while leaving the decimal point.

Then, just parse the string to a `double`:

```
String str = "$25.50";

double dbl = Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll("[^0-9,.]",""));
System.out.println(dbl);
```

In your code, you were removing the decimal point as well. Simply add the `,.` to your regex.